# What is the correct way to seed data in the dom for angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want seed the data I need for my javascript in the DOM as **I want to avoid an unnecessary call to the server to get this data**.

Usually I would add that data in the dom using a data attribute e.g.

```
<div data-record="{id: 1, name: 'name'}">
```

Then using jquery I would have done something like:

```
var record = $ele.data('record');
```

As this is a bad practice in Angular, I found that I can do something like this:

```
<div ng-init="record={id: 1, name: 'name'}">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
```

Then in my controller:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.record; //is available automatically with the data added in ng-init
```

Is this the right way to do this in Angular? Any better way? (Except doing an http request)

Thanks

Comment: The solution implemented by you is ok

Comment: Its ok, you could also just add the record right on the $scope in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

That's fine. Remember to run generated JSON through HTML escape to avoid XSS and other issues, e.g. in PHP:

```
<?php
$record = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'name');
?>
<div ng-init="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($record)); ?>"></div>
```